# Isomorphic induced subgraph problem using Courcelle's theorem

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, graph-isomorphism, parameterized-complexity

The isomorphic induced subgraph problem, is the problem of deciding whether, given two graphs $G$ and $H$, $G$ contains an induced subgraph isomorphic to $H$.
Is there a proof using Courcelle's theorem, that this problem is fixed-parameter tractable when parameterized by $|H|$ and $\mathrm{tw}(G)$ (treewidth)?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried to find such a proof?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I already checked online, there are plenty of material, but I couldn't find anywhere a proof of it using Courcelle's theorem. This [presentation](http://www-sop.inria.fr/teams/coati/events/grasta2014/slides/Kwon.pdf) talks about induced isomorphic subgraphs and Courcelle's theorem, but there isn't anything definitive.

Comment: Have you tried proving it yourself? Sometimes we want to prove something that nobody has proved before, and we are still able to do it.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No, I never tried to prove it. And I have no idea how to do it. This seems complicated to me. I mean basic things like clique, can easily be proved as $\mathbf{clique}(S) := \forall u \in S \space \forall v \in S \neg u = v \rightarrow \mathbf{adj}(u,v)$, but for this one I have no idea.

Comment: This is not too difficult to define in MSO$_2$. You know that $H$ has $k$ vertices, so then you want to say something about a subset of $k$ vertices from $G$ with some additional properties.

Comment: @Juho I can say $∀Y⊂V$, but how can I specify the size of the subset? I mean can I just say $∀Y⊂V∧|Y|=k$? And what additional properties are you talking about?

Comment: @opsorst Yes, you can just say there exists $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ such that... I suggest you try this yourself for the experience. If you want complete details or want to check your answer, see Flum & Grohe.